# Question with decimal result in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, variables, type-conversion, operation

I've got this doubt with operations between decimal and int values.

[image]

I do not understand why on a multiplication the result respect the definition of the variable (decimal(5,2)), but within a division I'm getting more decimals that expected.

Comment: [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) & [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the @myvar variable is delimited to have two decimals, but the result isn't

how about something like this ?

```
DECLARE @myvar as decimal(5,2)

set @myvar = 7

SELECT cast(@myvar/3 as decimal(5,2))
```

Comment: Hi @ignacio.ambia. Thanks for your replay. But look at the result of the multiplication, the result is the one expected: two decimals. But is not happening the same with the division.  That is my doubt.